# Gem:loaderror in Rails application due to nokogiri gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I've always getting an error saying `Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.3, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.2` so I decided to fix it.

I found this website http://www.railsbling.com/posts/fix_nokogiri_warning/ and followed the instruction. Now, whenever i run rails command like rails server and rails console, I always get an error saying

```
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'nokogiri' (>= 1.5.9) among 229 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0:/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global', execute `gem env` for more information
```

When I run bundle install in my rails app, I get long error log saying:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -r
./siteconf20160923-1257-12bvmq6.rb extconf.rb
Using pkg-config version 1.1.7
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts
-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.1.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv using --with-opt-* flags... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.4.

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.4.tar.gz into
tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.4... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.4... ERROR, review
'/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/compile.log'
to see what happened. Last lines are:
========================================================================
    unsigned short* in = (unsigned short*) inb;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
encoding.c:815:27: warning: cast from 'unsigned char *' to 'unsigned short *'
increases required alignment from 1 to 2 [-Wcast-align]
    unsigned short* out = (unsigned short*) outb;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
  CC       error.lo
  CC       parserInternals.lo
  CC       parser.lo
  CC       tree.lo
  CC       hash.lo
  CC       list.lo
  CC       xmlIO.lo
xmlIO.c:1450:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LZMA_OK'
    ret =  (__libxml2_xzclose((xzFile) context) == LZMA_OK ) ? 0 : -1;
                                                   ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [xmlIO.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
========================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:366:in
`block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
from
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in
`chdir'
from
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in
`execute'
from
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:111:in
`compile'
from
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:150:in
`cook'
    from extconf.rb:364:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:257:in `block in chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:363:in `block in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:262:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:262:in `process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:555:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8 for inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.8), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Not sure why Nokogiri is causing so much problem all of sudden.

Comment: Did you by change just upgrade to macOS Sierra? You need to reinstall libxml.

Answer (score 3):

I recently upgraded to Sierra and had issues with Nokogiri. I needed to reinstall nokogiri and link it to libxml2 in the appropriate MacOSX SDK directory

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/ --use-system-libraries
```